# Is (visit or go to guarantee) correct?

Tags: word-choice

What I would like to say is that you should go to the nearest store or the department where they can fix your mobile for free because you have a warranty.

what is the place that people visit when they have a warranty?

Comment: Service Dept/Repair Dept./Customer Service are common.

Comment: *Service provider location.* (Assuming you're going to the company from which you have a voice or data contract and that you got the phone from them.)  There are a wide range of terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term I have seen used most is **service centre**, which is defined by the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/service-centre) as

> a store or other place where you can have products, equipment, or vehicles checked and repaired and where you can buy parts